# NFS source code

Tags: linux, kernel, nfs, nfsclient

I'm looking for the source code of both NFS client and NFS server, in order to do so change inside the code, but unfortunately I was not able to find the source code.

Can anyone help, to locate their source codes? Are they located inside the linux kernel or they are external modules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are in the kernel source tree in directory "fs/nfs"

You can browse the latest code here (link updated 2020/11/13 as old one dead)

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/fs/nfs

Comment: this is a dead link now

Comment: Fixed link as old one dead.